# Is there a Regex Delete in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, ruby-1.9, gsub

All of my string delete's with regex use gsub, is there a shorter way?
`string.gsub(/\A.*\//,'')`

Comment: Those three characters really getting to you?

Comment: lol seem to be doing a lot of string deletes. But doing it via gsub, seems like I'm doing it wrong. It should be done via string.delete, no?

Comment: string.delete only takes what characters to delete, no regexp. string.slice! can be used to remove part of a string based on a regexp but is's longer then gsub...

Comment: `delete` doesn't take a regex. You can always create a String method like `gdel` or something that does what you want.

Comment: Do you need to do that in one position per string or multiple positions? Your expression has `gsub` (instead of `sub`) which means you are expecting multiple matches, but you also have `\A` in the regex, which means you are expecting only one match. Depending on that, solutions become different.

Comment: Multiple positions, sorry copied one of the gsubs as a poor example. I'm just surprised delete doesn't incorporate regex. Seems like it'll be more consistent with Ruby's ideology if it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to add your own short methods:

```
class String

  def del(regexp)
    gsub(regexp,'')
  end

  def del!(regexp)
    gsub!(regexp,'')
  end

end
```

Typically this code would go in a lib/ directory, for example lib/string-extensions.rb

Heads up that some programmers really dislike this because it's monkey-patching. I personally like it for projects because it makes code easier to understand - once I have the "del" method, I can quickly see that calls to it are just deleting the regexp.

Answer (score 5):

You could instead specify the part of the string you want to *keep* . . .

```
string[/[^\/]*$/]
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.

String::delete deletes characters, and does not match regex, it's a completely different approach.

The only way I can think of making that line of yours "shorter" is to use `string.gsub!(/\A.*\//,'')` (notice the bang there).

That's the way to go, I think :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ***String::delete*** by specifying a regex in the argument.


Say you want to delete all non *AlphaNumeric* from a string...

```
a="Test String with &(*ille#*)gal char!@#acters ^lorem % ipsum $"

a.delete!('^a-zA-Z0-9 .')
```

*Ofcourse be careful to include **Whitespace** and **DOT***

Above code will yield the following output

```
"Test String with illegal characters lorem  ipsum "
```

This is just an example.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I haven't been able to use delete with POSIX bracket expressions like `[[:word:]]`. Is it possible? https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes